# Login into a website with python and selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to auto login to a website. When the main page loads, It has a login button, which brings up the login form with `username` and `password` forms.

The button is inside a `div` element with an id equal to '`loginbox`':

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 text-right" id="loginbox">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-10">
<button type="button" class="btn btnlogin" data-toggle="modal" data-
target="#loginDiv">
```

This is my code for finding the button, and then clicking it:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('websiteURL') 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='loginbox']/button[1]").click()
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
"Unable to locate element: //div[@id='loginbox']/button[1]"
```

How should I locate this button?

This is the rest of my code for filling `username` and `password` inputs:

```
username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "FRMLoginUname")))
username.clear()
username.send_keys('UserName')

password = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "FRMLoginPassword")))
password.clear()
password.send_keys('Password')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because `loginbox` is loaded by ajax or jquery.
You should use [selenium Waits.](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) There is two type of waits explicit and implicit.*Avoid using implicit wait.*

```
# Explicit wait example
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element_login_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'loginbox')))


# implicit wait example
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='loginbox']/button[1]").click()
```

Comment: On my computer, with the driver for Firefox I need to use a wait() function, whereas with the driver for Chrome I don't. I think that with Chrome, it blocks until the page is fully loaded.

Comment: @VincentVidal ,Yes but in above question user uses Firefox driver

Comment: @Himanshudua Thanks a lot! I was able to successfully login to the website.

Comment: @VincentVidal, Thank you for mentioning the difference between Chrome and Firefox drivers. It's a great thing to know.

Comment: I don't think either browser behaves differently in blocking until the page is loaded. In my experience Chrome is just faster and is less likely to need a wait like Firefox or IE.

Comment: @L1nu5 Please accept the answer if resolve your problem\